# General solution for $M^{\circ -1 }(y)=x $ when $g(x)e^{f(x) }=y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, special-functions, inverse

Reading this question [$e^{C/x }-1=D/(x + a) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397312/generalisation-of-lambert-w-function#comment850397_397312), i found my self completely unable to do anything. This is much more hard for me than my easy exercises about Lambert $W$-function.

So I probably need more training and exercise. Anyways thinking a bit about it I guess that the problem can be generalized in: find the inverse function $M^{-1} (x)$ of $M (x)=g(x)e^{f(x) }=y$ such that

$$g(M^{-1}(x))e^{f(M^{-1}(x)) }=x$$

and the easier case is when  $W^{-1}(x)=xe^{x }=y$ and the inverse is the Lambert $W$

$$W(x) e^{W(x)}=x$$

at this point I can't not see that there is a relation between the solution of the first and the lambert function, and is that $M$ have a weird property

$$g(M^{-1}(x))e^{f(M^{-1}(x)) }=W(x) e^{W(x)}$$

then is possible to conclude that such such $M$ must hold:

$$f\circ M=g \circ M=W$$

but this does not make any sense (it does? If yes then for $M$ must hold $(f^{-1}\circ g)\circ M=M$ for every $f$ and $g$), and at this point I'm lost.

---

***Questions***

$1$) How we can find a general solution when $f$ and $g$ are invertible?

> $$g(x)e^{f(x) }=y$$

$2$) What I am missing in my observation?

Comment: In the link you have posted the $x$ dependence is clear and I could imagine a solution at some value of $x$. What you have here is a little confusing, what exactly is it you are trying to solve for? It seems to me you could have $g(x)=ye^{-f(x)}$ and $f(x)$ arbitrary...

Comment: yes @GrahamHesketh you are right, I'll edit the question, is a bit confusing. Anyways anyways before i edit, the meaning is the Lambert $W$ function make us able to find the $x$ when we have $xe^x=y$, but what we do if we have $(a+b/x)e^{x^k+c }=y$ for example? The general case is find the $x$ if we have $ g(x)e^{f(x) }=y$? Is enough clear? I'm surely missing something, but this is my problem.